# How to redirect deny users to a page using ACL CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Currently in my login system using ACL of CakePHP, when the user has insufficient privileges the system redirect to the current page. e.g, i have access in `/posts/` and i'm there, i'll to try access `/posts/add` that i have no privileges, the system redirect the user to the same page `/posts/`, i need custom it, redirect to a page like 404 error or display a warning message.

Looking for answers in SOen i found [Cakephp ACL redirect when a user has insufficient privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953035/cakephp-acl-redirect-when-a-user-has-insufficient-privileges) but the post is so old and the accepted answer seems no good.

Comment: with same logic https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#using-http-exceptions-in-your-controllers

Comment: I need do a condition for each method in my controller? So there isn't a way to do it directly from ACL?

Comment: Use the [**`unauthorizedRedirect` option**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuration-options) if you need to specify a custom redirect URL, or set it to `false` so that an exception is thrown wich you could catch (in an overridden `Controller::invokeAction()` for example).

Comment: @ndm works fine, thank you.